# Could investors plot to trade shares of a company in an attempt to raise its stock valuation?

Tags: corporate-law

Could a circle of investors (plotting together) trade among themselves shares of a start-up company to make the company look as a worthy investment?

For example, the company has 10,000 shares and they buy 1,000 for $1,000 each to make the company look like $10,000,000 worth. Alternatively, they exchange 1,000 shares of one company created by them for 1,000 shares of a new company and claim it to be a deal worth $1,000,000.

Is that a common and viable strategy? Are laws protecting future investors against this kind of games?

Answer (score 4):

Very simply, that's called a conspiracy to commit fraud with investment instruments. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conspiracy

> Is that a common and viable strategy?

It happens, though because it is illegal, it's probably *(hopefully)* not common. And since it's illegal, generally speaking, people view it as not very viable.

> Are laws protecting future investors against this kind of games?

Yes. Read:

Securities Fraud https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Securities_fraud

> *Securities fraud, also known as stock fraud and investment fraud, is a
>   deceptive practice in the stock or commodities markets that induces
>   investors to make purchase or sale decisions on the basis of false
>   information, frequently resulting in losses, in violation of
>   securities laws*

In particular:

Pump and Dump: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pump_and_dump

> *Pump and dump" (P&D) is a form of microcap stock fraud that involves
>   artificially inflating the price of an owned stock through false and
>   misleading positive statements, in order to sell the cheaply purchased
>   stock at a higher price.*

Insider Trading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insider_trading

> *Insider trading is the trading of a public company's stock or other
>   securities (such as bonds or stock options) by individuals with access
>   to nonpublic information about the company. In various countries,
>   trading based on insider information is illegal.*

And: The regulatory and enforcement agency is the U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission

> *The U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission "holds primary
>   responsibility for enforcing the federal securities laws, proposing
>   securities rules, and regulating the securities industry, the nation's
>   stock and options exchanges, and other activities and organizations,
>   including the electronic securities markets in the United States."
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Securities_and_Exchange_Commission*